# Opening .docx files in Google Docs when opening the files with Chromium or Firefox

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, chromium, firefox-extensions, chrome-extension

When I had chrome installed, I would open a **.docx** file with chrome, and it would open the file and give me an option to open it in **Google Docs** as well.

Now I moved to chromium, and want to do the same thing, but can't figure out how to do it.

I guess it is probably an **extension**, or an **add-on** I need to install.

If I can do it in **Firefox**, it will be even better.

I would be grateful if you can help.

Comment: You can open Google Docs *then* open the file. Chromium (or Firefox) doesn't have the Google proprietary code that allows such integration with Google services.